# How to implement Single-Sign-On for Electron?

Tags: electron, single-sign-on

I am currently building an Electron app, which is supposed to download files from the companies cloud services e.g. SharePoint. Our company uses SSO in browsers like Chromium, which works out of the box. I would like to implement this for my app, as well. Since Electron is based on Chromium it should be easy to configure, but where to start?

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented SSO in my application. I have used something called as **webView** provided by electron.

```
// WebView can be used to open any third party application inside our client window. (Ex- SSO provider's website)

<div className="webViewContainer">
   <webview src={webViewUrl} webpreferences="nodeIntegration=false" className="webView"></webview>
</div>
```

Here is the detailed description about webview by [electron](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag)